# Convert LaTeX Equation to SymPy [Julia] format

Tags: latex, julia, sympy

I'm trying to convert LaTeX to SymPy understandable format in Julia version. My latex formulas may involve matrix and other notations. A simple example is:

```
$\left[ \frac{(\theta - 1)(1 - \zeta_{n,s})c\beta}{\theta w a } \right]$
```

Is there any way to automatically convert this equation into its sympy version for Julia?

Comment: I’d guess one of these works https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html but have never tried.

Comment: I don't know about that last recommendation. I couldn't figure out how to access the feature. If you can, please post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For clarity, I will call the Python version of SymPy, SymPy and I will call the Julia wrapper SymPy.jl.

For LaTeX parsing, SymPy needs the additional package `antlr4` which is called `antlr4-python3-runtime` on the Conda website.

Then, SymPy.jl does not seem to have the `sympy.parsing.latex` module. I might just be too stupid to get to it, but I had to use PyCall for the parsing itself.

Note that antlr4 does not like subscripts of the form `_{...}`. This means that it will crash with the `\zeta_{n,s}` in your expression. I just changed it to `\zeta(n, s)` below.

To check that we can use the expression with SymPy.jl, I just added a random symbol to the expression and it seems to have worked.

```
# intall antlr4
using PyCall
run(`$(PyCall.python) -m pip install --upgrade antlr4-python3-runtime`)

# parse the expression
s = raw"\left[ \frac{(\theta - 1)(1 - \zeta(n,s))c\beta}{\theta w a } \right]"
using PyCall
latex = pyimport("sympy.parsing.latex")
expr = latex.parse_latex(s)

# check that we can interact with the expression
using SymPy
expr = expr + sympy.Symbol("y")
```